# What is meant by "An Object" when we use Str() Function in R

Tags: r

Everyone states that `str()` shows the structure of an object by showing observations (rows) and variables (columns). Do we treat a dataset as an object in R?

Comment: A dataframe is an object in R, yes.

Comment: @BillO'Brien Then what we will say regarding "a <- 10". Is "a"  also an object ?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science)) has a good explanation

Comment: @G5W Do we treat a dataset as an object ?

Comment: http://archive.linux.duke.edu/cran/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of this knowledge can be found in the R manual on cran, named [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Objects). I really can't state it any more clearly than the manual itself, as such i will quote the section used.

> The entities R operates on are technically known as objects. Examples are vectors of numeric (real) or complex values, vectors of logical values and vectors of character strings. These are known as “atomic” structures since their components are all of the same type, or mode, namely numeric, complex, logical, character and raw.

Basically from the documentation anything that is directly workable from the R session is coerced into what is technically known as an `object` in the R language. As such this includes anything we use, such as `data.frame`s, `function`s, `name`s, `formula`s, `expression`s and so on.

The `str` function basically expands the object showing the structure of any contained object. For example `str(list(A = 1:3, b = sum, c = data.frame(A = 4:6, b = (4:6)^2)))` would expands to the tree-like output

```
>str(list(A = 1:3, b = sum, c = data.frame(A = 4:6, b = (4:6)^2)))
List of 3
 $ A: int [1:3] 1 2 3
 $ b:function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  
 $ c:'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ A: int [1:3] 4 5 6
  ..$ b: num [1:3] 16 25 36
```

Albeit i would guess there is some depth limit to how far it expands.

In short, anything you store within the `R` environment is considered an `object`.